# Copy Oracle database from Amazon RDS to a local Oracle developer edition database

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle SE database that we run in Amazon's RDS service as our production database.  I am looking for techniques and/or tools to duplicate the database to a developer edition database that the development team can run on their local systems.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate dump file and transfer it to your local/standalone unix system where oracle is installed. and then import dump file data.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have direct access to the RDS instance file system.

There are several data migration solutions.

The first solution using S3 Bucket.

1. Use DBMS_DATAPUMP to export to DUMP File on the RDS Instance.
2. Copy Dump File from the RDS instance to Amazon S3 Bucket.
3. Download the dump file from the S3 cloud to the developer edition database.
4. Import data from the dump file using expdp on the developer edition database.

The second solution using Database Link between the RDS Instance and the developer edition database.

1. Create a Database Link on the RDS Instance to the developer edition database.
2. Use DBMS_DATAPUMP to export to DUMP File on the RDS Instance.
3. Use DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER to Copy the Dump File from the RDS Instance to the developer edition database.
4. Import data from the dump file using expdp on the developer edition database.

The third solution using Oracle XE, if you cannot make a db link between the developer edition database and RDS instance.

1. Use DBMS_DATAPUMP to export to DUMP File on the RDS Instance.
2. Create a free instance of EC2(1 CPU core, 1G RAM, 30GD HDD ) or a
   paid instance with a large disk and CPU.
3. Install a free database version of the Oracle XE version on EC2
   instance.
4. Create a Database Link on the RDS Instance to the Oracle XE.
5. Use DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER to Copy the Dump File from the RDS Instance to the Oracle XE.
6. Copy files from the Oracle XE on EC2 instance via the sftp protocol on your PC.
7. Copy files from your PC to the developer edition database.
8. Import data from the dump file using expdp on the developer edition
   database.

And other solutions without using DATA PUMP:

1. Export/Import Using Oracle SQL Developer.
2. Oracle Original Export/Import Original Utilities